# Conan: установка зависимостей

Tags: c++, conan

Как установить все зависимости для пакета?
Пытаюсь установить cpprestsdk. В зависимостях к этому пакету - bzip2, lzma, boost и т.д. На данный момент после каждого нового фэйла я добавляю очередной пакет в команду и пытаюсь заново. Выглядит это как-то так:

```
conan install ../conanfile.txt --profile=gcc --build lzma
conan install ../conanfile.txt --profile=gcc --build lzma --build boost_regex
conan install ../conanfile.txt --profile=gcc --build lzma --build boost_regex --build boost_conatiner
// e.t.c.
```

Я понимаю, что установленные пакеты можно повторно не включать - но ситуации это помогает мало.

Содержимое *conanfile.txt*:

```
[requires]
cpprestsdk/2.10.2@bincrafters/stable
gtest/1.8.1@bincrafters/stable

[generators]
cmake
```

Env.:
macOS, gcc 8.3

Comment: `install` должен устанавливать зависимости

Comment: @VTT, возможно я что-то делаю не так, но - нет, не устанавливает.

Comment: ну а что у вас в conanfile.txt написано?

Comment: @VTT, обновил вопрос.